# Браузер для IOS

Tags: ios, xcode

Подскажите источники, где можно почитать информацию как написать браузер на `Objective-C` для `IOS`.

Comment: последних 10 лет гугл помогает...

Comment: маааленький вопросик, а оно вам надо ?

Comment: Для начала почитайте какие возможности предоставляет iOS SDK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

С большего вас интересует отображение веб-контента, это делается с помощью UIWebView, вот [тут рассказано](http://idev.by/ios/4259/) как с ним работать.

А дальше просто придумываете свой интерфейс, в котором будет несколько UIWebView (табы как в Safari).